# Find limit when $\theta$ tends to $0$ of $\tan(\theta) /\theta$

Tags: limits

I understand that $\lim_{\theta\to0}(\sin(θ)/θ) = 1$ but what is $x$ when, 
$\lim_{\theta\to0}(\tan(θ)/θ) = x$ where $x$ is a real constant value.

Please help me, I will be eternally great full :D

Comment: Hint: $\tan\theta={\sin\theta\over\cos\theta}$.

Comment: Yes I know that but I dont know how to use that :P

Comment: Write ${\tan\theta\over\theta}={1\over\cos\theta}{\sin\theta\over\theta}$. Then use the fact that a limit of a product is the product of the limits, when they all exist.

Comment: I get something like (\tan\theta\over\theta}={\sin\theta\over\cos\theta*theta}

Comment: oh thanks so much David

Answer (score 4):

We have that $\dfrac{\tan\theta}{\theta}=\dfrac{1}{\cos\theta}\cdot \dfrac {\sin\theta}{\theta}.$

Then recall that the limit of a product is equal to the product of the limits (when those limits do in fact exist.)

$$\lim_{\theta\to 0} \dfrac{\tan\theta}{\theta}= \lim_{\theta\to 0} \dfrac{\sin\theta}{(\cos\theta)\cdot \theta}=\lim_{\theta \to 0} \dfrac{1}{\cos\theta}\cdot \dfrac {\sin\theta}{\theta} = \lim_{\theta \to 0} \dfrac 1{\cos \theta} \cdot \lim_{\theta\to 0} \dfrac{\sin \theta}{\theta} = 1\cdot 1 = 1.$$

Answer (score 0):

I'll use $x$ instead of $\theta$.

Use the identity:

$$\tan(x) = \frac{\sin x}{\cos x}$$

By limit rules,

$$\lim_{x \ \to 0} \frac{f(x)}{g(x)} = \frac{\lim_{x \ \to 0} f(x)}{\lim_{x \ \to 0} g(x)}$$

Thus:

$$\lim_{x \to 0} \sin x = 0.$$
$$\lim_{x \to 0} \cos x = 1.$$

You want to find $$\lim_{x \to 0} \frac{\tan x}{x}$$ which is $$\lim_{x \to 0} \frac{\sin x}{\cos x} \cdot \frac{1}{x} = \frac{0}{0}$$ , you've got $\frac{0}{0}$ then have to use HLopital's rule.

$$\lim_{x \to 0} \frac{(\sin x)'}{(x \cos x)'} = \lim_{x \to 0} \frac{\cos x}{\cos x - x \sin x} = \frac{1}{1} = 1.$$

Answer (score -3):

$x=1$

Let $\theta=y$. Then $$\tan y=\frac{\sin y}{\cos y}$$ 
and $\lim_{y \to 0} \frac{\sin y}{y}=1$ and $\cos 0=1$ so $\lim_{y\to 0}\frac{\tan y}{y}=0$.

Comment: The answer is essentially right, with a typo at the end.

Comment: @user124200 Yes, looks like it's just a typo.